# Expresso Store, State Field Label instead of Code

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to map the actual state instead of state code to the native member fields.

At the moment i get, CON instead of CONWY.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the states.php file inside Store > data on your third_party directory. It returns a key / value array. Just make sure it complies with your Shipping & Payment Gateway required fields.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, Thanks for reply. I'm not quite sure what you mean? There is a states.php file in store > config > states.php. Is this where you mean?

Comment: There should be yes, depending on what version of Store you are using. Most shipping gateways and some Payment gateways will fail however using the state name oppose to the state code

Comment: Having said that you can always use the `{shipping_state_name}` or `{billing_state_name}` variable in your templates to output the actual name instead of the state code. https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#shipping_state_name